# FileHelper reading csv file freezing

Tags: c#, csv, file-io, filehelpers

I am trying to use FileHelper to read a csv file, in which data are arranged like this:
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,......
1kX1k of them.
Here is my FileHelper code:

```
[DelimitedRecord(",")] 
    public class ROIMaskCSV 
    { 
        public int value;

        //[TransformToRecord(typeof(ROIMaskCSV[]))]
        public static ROIMaskCSV[] loadMask(string fileName)
        {

            DelimitedFileEngine engine = new DelimitedFileEngine(typeof(ROIMaskCSV));

            ROIMaskCSV[] mask = (ROIMaskCSV[])engine.ReadFile(fileName); 

           // mask[0].value = this.value;

            return mask;
        }
    }
```

And here is where FileHelper loadMask() function gets called:

```
public class TIFFIImageIO
{
    public static int LoadTIFF(string fileName, int x, int y)
    {

        ROIMaskCSV[] mask = ROIMaskCSV.loadMask("d:\\myMask.csv");
        ......
```

I stepped in, so when program gets:

```
 ROIMaskCSV[] mask = (ROIMaskCSV[])engine.ReadFile(fileName);
```

the program is just freezed. I am not sure what happened. Something I did wrong? Anyone can give some pointers? Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: How much time did you give it? Is it possible it's just slow?

Comment: I would say on mins. It does not look right to me.....

Comment: Is the program still using CPU?

Comment: have you tried writing code that reads and Splits the code without using FileHelper..?

Comment: @AnnL. I actually think it is not using CPU. I open task manager, and the program is not on top that consumes much CPU resources.

Comment: @DJKRAZE: Because I have seen good review of FileHelper, so I think it is worth trying to see how it performs.

Comment: Well based on what you are stating doesn't seem like it's `performing` quite so well.. perhaps you are implementing it incorrectly as well

Comment: @DJKRAZE: Yeah, so I need to know which one, poor performance or my bad (probably my bad). That is why I posted my code here hoping someone gives some hint. This is the first time I am using FileHelper.

Comment: have you looked at any of their links or support links [FileHelpers library](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/) [FileHelpers Example of how to use](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Yes, I went to their website, and basically followed their tutorail of delimited data reading. My code is based on their example. However, I now have a problem.

Comment: perhaps there is an issue in your data.. like multiple commas in a string can you show what the file looks like..? if not try to create a sample file that has 2 to 3 lines test that and see if you are experiencing the same Performance Issue..?

Comment: @DJKRAZE: Does that mean my code looks fine?

Comment: Only you would know that.. since you are working from an example I would guess and say yes.. but that's something that you would only know..

Comment: OK. I give up. I will just stream read the file, then parse it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK. I give up. I will just stream read the file, then parse it. This is the code I read my csv file:

```
byte[] array = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
```

Then convert array[i] to char/int, or whatever type you want.

To char, for example to convert ASC II 65 to 'A':

```
char.ConvertFromUtf32(65);
```

To int, for example to convert ASC II 48 to 0:

```
Convert.ToInt32(char.ConvertFromUtf32(48));
```